# EmberJS - each page with a controller linked without router

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ember.js

I'm trying to develop an EmberJS application with ASP.NET MVC. I've found the SPA Template (thanks for developers, it's awesome!), but I want to do a different approach. Instead the SPA (Single-Page Application) approach, I want to use the ASP.NET routes and pages, like a commmon ASP.NET MVC app. The issue is: I want in every new page I can add a `<script>` tag referencing the controller will be used in that page, you know?

Something like that:

The shared page contains the main references to EmberJS (app.js contains the initialization of EmberJS):

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...EmberJS reference blahblah...
    </head>
    ...
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EmberJS/app.js")" />
</html>
```

Well, let's suppose I'll create a Customer page. I know I have to create a CustomerController to handle the page. Let's suppose too I'll create a `CustomerController.js` file.

```
App.CustomerController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    customers: [],
    ...
});
```

Then, I'll create a `Customer.cshtml`, which will be the page to display the actions about Customers. I want to do something like this above:

```
<ul>
{{#each customer in controller.customers}}
    <li>{{customer.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

...
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EmberJS/Controllers/CustomerController.js")" />
```

So, I'll need a way to synchronize this Controller I've added with the `<script>` tag to my page and make the controller understandable to the page.

1. Is this possible?
2. If yes, how can I link the CustomerController to any page I want? I need to use View or something else?

Thanks you, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember is specifically designed for creating Single Page Apps.  If you don't want to create a SPA you should probably look at using something other than Ember.

Comment: Good point, I can't imagine an Ember app teared apart across multiple pages.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion? I want to use data-binding, computed properties, caching... these things Ember has, you know?